# C++ Largest Numerical Storage

Tags: c++, c++11, int, unsigned, unsigned-long-long-int

Is there an equivalent to Java's Bigint in C++ that can store the following number:

`567014094304930933548155069494723691156768423655208899778686163624192868328194365094673392756508907687565332345345678900976543567890976543565789054335678097654680986564323567890876532456890775646780976543556789054367890765435689876545898876587907876535976565578907654538790878656543687656543467898786565457897675645657689756456578656456768654657898865567689656890795587907654678798765787897865654657897654678965465786867278762795432151914451557727529104757415030674806148138138281214236089749601911974949125689884222023119844272122501649909415937`

I've looked at unsigned long long int but that is not nearly as big enough to store that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check these:

- [C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/)
- [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)
- [TTMath](http://www.ttmath.org/)

Answer (score 4):

No. There is lot of libraries for BigInt C++. For example [boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/libs/multiprecision/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no stadard C++ type for such a big numbers.
You might need to use one of the library for big numbers: [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), [MAPM](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html) or [bigint](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/)