# C++ Boost Large Number Storage

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, int, gmp

So based on the [question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196232/c-largest-numerical-storage), I downloaded and setup boost. I have this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost\multiprecision\gmp.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

void main() {
    mpz_int N(567014094304930933548155069494723691156768423655208899778686163624192868328194365094673392756508907687565332345345678900976543567890976543565789054335678097654680986564323567890876532456890775646780976543556789054367890765435689876545898876587907876535976565578907654538790878656543687656543467898786565457897675645657689756456578656456768654657898865567689656890795587907654678798765787897865654657897654678965465786867278762795432151914451557727529104757415030674806148138138281214236089749601911974949125689884222023119844272122501649909415937);

}
```

But when I compile it says

```
IntelliSense: integer constant is too large
```

If mpz_int is not what I'm supposed to use, then what should I use for large ints from boost?

Comment: With gmpxx, you could just write `567014094304930933548155069494723691156768423655208899778686163624192868328194365094673392756508907687565332345345678900976543567890976543565789054335678097654680986564323567890876532456890775646780976543556789054367890765435689876545898876587907876535976565578907654538790878656543687656543467898786565457897675645657689756456578656456768654657898865567689656890795587907654678798765787897865654657897654678965465786867278762795432151914451557727529104757415030674806148138138281214236089749601911974949125689884222023119844272122501649909415937_mpz`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Construct it from string. You can use `mpz_int` or `cpp_int`.

http://liveworkspace.org/code/1KKxfm$6

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to construct from an integer literal: which is exactly that, a literal of type "int" and only capable of holding "int" sized values.  You can either:

1) Place your large integer constant in quotes, so that the value is constructed from a string, or
2) With cpp_int only, use the user-defined literal support to construct from an extended precision literal, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/lits.html  Note that this requires a C++11 compiler - VC++ that you're using does not yet have the necessary language features to support this.  Note that this is true constexpr initialization, not the hidden construct-from-string-at-runtime that gmpxx uses (necessarily given that memory allocation is required).